# Drop rows with 'NoneType' and with strings: keep only numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset in which one of the columns has empty rows and some strings, whereas I only need to keep the numeric ones.

I have tried this for the strings:

```
df_3 = df_cor_inc[['Person ID','rt']]
df5 = df_3.to_csv('Documents/a.csv',index=False)
df5['rt'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce')).dropna()
```

But I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'.

This doesn't work either because 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rt':

```
df5[df5.rt.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

Same thing happens when I try to get rid of the empty rows, I get an error because I have 'NoneType'. How do I get rid of it so that I only keep the numeric values of that column and delete all the rows that don't have them?

This is how the data looks:

```
Person ID,rt
0,445   
0,445   
0,445   
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,Wait success  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,  
1,1230  
1,1230  
1,1230  
1,1230  
1,1230  
1,1230  
1,1721  
1,1721  
1,1721  
1,1721  
1,1721  
1,1721
```

Comment: What is code before? Seems `df5` is `Nonetype`, not `DataFrame`

Comment: @jezrael oh, I added it. It comes from another dataframe and then I selected only two columns and saved them into a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is ouput variable is set to `None` if write `df_3` by `to_csv` to file.

```
df5 = df_3.to_csv('Documents/a.csv',index=False)
```

Solution is working only with `df_3` like:

```
df_3 = df_cor_inc[['Person ID','rt']]
#no assign to df5
df_3.to_csv('Documents/a.csv',index=False)

#assigned converted values to numeric
df_3['rt'] = pd.to_numeric(df_3['rt'], errors = 'coerce')
#removed NaNs rows by rt column
df5 = df_3.dropna(subset=['rt'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the part about the file but I still get some errors when it comes to dropping the rows. With the first option: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. With the second option: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Comment: @AnuragDabas - I copy it from OP, you are right.